# Object recognition based on its movement

Tags: classification, object-recognition

Models like YOLO, Detectron2, etc. classify objects based on their appearance.
This is great when we have single images, and we want to classify objects within those images. However, video contains a lot more data, and the movement of an object within a sequence of frames should also be a great way to classify objects.

For example, a bird and an aircraft may look visually similar, but their movement over a period of e.g., 2 or 5 seconds will give a much better indication as to what the object is (e.g., the bird may make a sharp turn and appear erratic, while an aircraft follows a predictable trajectory).

Are there any open source models that consider the motion of objects within a video, in order to do classification?